# Increasing the size of windows boot partition

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation, boot-partition

So I have read that I can install linux's boot partition on the same boot partition as windows. I want to do this so I can have windows be in my bootloader. But linux needs 500 MiB for it and it only has 100 MiB. How can I make it bigger, gparted says it is already max size.

My parted -l:

```
Model: ATA HGST HTS721010A9 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 1000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    File system     Name                          Flags

 1      1049kB  106MB   105MB   fat32           EFI system partition          boot, esp
 2      106MB   240MB   134MB                   Microsoft reserved partition  msftres
 3      240MB   881GB   881GB   ntfs            Basic data partition          msftdata
 6      881GB   887GB   5268MB  linux-swap(v1) - I added in gparted for linux
 7      887GB   969GB   82.3GB  ext4 - I added in gparted for linux
 4      980GB   981GB   839MB   ntfs            Basic data partition          hidden, diag
 5      981GB   1000GB  19.4GB  ntfs            Basic data partition          hidden, diag
```

Comment: Do not confuse an ESP - efi system partition with Ubuntu Boot partition if UEFI. Or if old BIOS, Windows boot partition has to be NTFS and Ubuntu only works from ext4 format. Ubuntu desktop normally does not need /boot partition unless LVM or encrypted  install which works best if not dual booting. Post this above. `sudo parted -l`

Comment: @oldfred there I put it in and labeled what ones I added for linux

Comment: You have an UEFI based system with UEFI installs? Windows has to be UEFI as it only installs in UEFI boot mode to gpt partitioned drive. Ubuntu installs or repairs  in mode you boot installer, so always boot in UEFI mode. You did not need swap as Ubuntu desktop now uses a swap file, but swap partition will be used it found. If fast start up is off grub will find Windows & add it to menu. And with UEFI you can always boot Windows from UEFI. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI & https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-10-with-uefi

Comment: @oldfred I am actually using Pop!_Os and I posted here because I was told it was based off of ubuntu and so the ubuntu community could help with errors. In the installer it says I need a /boot partition so should I just create a new one?

Comment: This is an Ubuntu only, Pop!OS is different, even though based on Ubuntu. Only official Ubuntu flavors are supported here. It is my understanding that it requires a larger ESP, as it puts kernel & drivers into the ESP, not in a /boot partition. Better to ask on https://unix.stackexchange.com/ or https://ubuntuforums.org/forumdisplay.php?f=452